# How to enable logging in slf4j using command line only (No properties file)

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I am trying to figure out how to enable a granular level of logging using `slf4j-jdk14:1.7.25` version. Till now I have tried numerous ways to enable it, but somehow none of them is overriding default logging level.

This question combines **two sub-questions**:

1. How to identify which logging.properties is being used? if we don't have one (OR How can I list what all properties are being implied to my package)?
2. How to set a specific log level to a package if we don't have `logging.properties` file? (I don't want to add one as I do not own the repo)

Adding the sample test program for easy testing:

```java
package com.learning.examples;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class LogTest {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogTest.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LOG.trace("This is trace level");
    LOG.debug("This is debug level");
    LOG.info("This is info level");
    LOG.warn("This is warn level");
    LOG.error("This is error level");
  }
}
```

As of now my app has these two dependencies:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.25</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Till now I have tried these combinations:

```sh
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.learning.examples.LogTest \
  -Dsl4j.rootLogger=DEBUG

mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.learning.examples.LogTest \
  -Djava.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL/FINEST/FINE/DEBUG

mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.learning.examples.LogTest \
  -Dhandlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler \
  -Dcom.learning.examples.level=DEBUG

mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.learning.examples.LogTest \
  -Dcom.learning.examples.level=DEBUG

mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.learning.examples.LogTest \
  -Dlogging.level.com.learning.examples=DEBUG

mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.learning.examples.LogTest \
  -Dlog.level.com.learning.examples=DEBUG
```

I just want to see logs of the various level without introducing any files into my repository or without changing the dependencies.

Comment: Have you set the handlers as well - `handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too with /without log level.